# Separator Lines still present in Xamarin.Forms TableView

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tableview

Ok, I followed the Xamarin example for setting up a custom renderer for a TableView to hide the separator.

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/listview-hide-separator-line/

I also found and followed this example:
https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/Evolve13/Evolve13/Views/MenuPage.cs

https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/Evolve13/Evolve13.Android/MenuTableViewRenderer.cshttps://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/Evolve13/Evolve13.Android/MenuTableViewRenderer.cs

https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/Evolve13/Evolve13.iOS/MenuTableViewRenderer.cs

Neither of these were working so a found a third way that is basically a variant on the original.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37660/tableview-separatorvisibility

Still none of these are working

My code is below.

```
        var section = new TableSection
        {
            EntryCellItem,
        };

        var root = new TableRoot { section };

        var table = new MenuTableView()
        {
            Intent = TableIntent.Menu,
            Root = root,
        };

public Class MenuTableView(){}
```

I am using the basics of the Xamarin Tutorial. The only differences are, instead 
of listView.DividerHeight = 0; it's set to -1, and an additional listView.Divide = (i don't want to type out android color).Transparent;

This isn't some random Emulator problem, I have tested it on an android tablet.
I don't have an ios device to test on yet.

Is there anything I have done wrong? Just really needing some help here.

Answer (score 0):

This is very old [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=36911). Now it is not working(DividerHeight = 0). Try use ListView with SeparatorVisibility = None